# How to conditionally render React components based on user permissions

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for a secure way to render React components based on a users permissions.  I know I can use props like `props.userStore.isAdmin` to conditionally render a component:

```
{
  this.props.userStore.isAdmin ? <AdminDashboard /> : null 
}
```

but could a user modify those props to gain access to an admin dashboard?

I have the controller on the backend (rails) secured with the pundit gem, so the user would not be able to actually use the admin dashboard to do damage, but I'd still rather them not be able to access it all.  Is this possible with React?

Comment: Any code and data you send is modifiable--so if you want to completely eliminate knowledge you need to send less code and data. This is problematic since in general you'll be shipping out a single JS app file.

Comment: You could uglify but as long as you have appropriate authorization on the back end then no need to worry if someone can get access to the "View" as all requests would fail from that point

Comment: I guess then it's not the end of the world if a malicious user can see the admin dash but not interact with it.  Thanks for your input!